# How to edit or delete App registrations in azure using Rest API

Tags: azure, rest, microsoft-graph-api

I have created the azure app registration on Azure AD B2C using rest API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/applications.

but i can't able to delete the App or edit the app using this api, [https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/${applicationId}?api-version=1.6](https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/$%7BapplicationId%7D?api-version=1.6).

It always return 401 unauthorized error but i have passed the correct authorization token

Comment: Can you confirm the role in the access_token ?

Answer (score 1):

I created an Azure AD B2C application and granted **`Application.ReadWrite.All`** Application permission:

[image]

I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope↵:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When decodes **roles** are present:

[image]

I **created the Azure AD B2C application** using above access token:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "testrukb2capp"
}
```

[image]

**To edit the application**, I used the same query and got **`401`** error:

```json
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/applications/ID?api-version=1.6

{
"displayName": "newrukb2capp"
}
```

[image]

The error is because you are making use of [**Azure Active Directory Graph**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/end-of-support-for-azure-ad-graph-permission-sign-up-through/ba-p/2464404) query which is deprecated and using token generated for Microsoft Graph.

**To resolve the error,** make use of Microsoft Graph query to update the application:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/ObjectID
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "newrukb2capp"
}
```

[image]

***The application display name updated successfully:***

[image]

**To delete the application,** make use of below query:

```json
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/ObjectID
```

[image]

***Application deleted successfully:***

[image]

If you are using user-interaction flows, then grant **`Application.ReadWrite.All`** delegated API permission.

**References:**

[Update application - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Delete application - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)